# How to test that only specific methods of a mock were called with PHPUnit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have a class I want to mock and make sure that only one of its methods was called. How can I construct such a mock object in PHPUnit? Something like

```
public function testSystemUnderTestOnlyInvokesFoo() {
    $myMock = $this->createMock(ClassWithManyMethods::class);
    $myMock->expects($this->once())->method('foo');

    // Something like this
    // $myMock->expects($this->never)->method($this->anyMethodExcept('foo'))

    function_under_test($myMock);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `method` function accepts both a string and a `Constraint` class. A PHPUnit test can create constraint classes with utility functions like `isNull`, `contains` or `matches`. In the example, `anyMethodExcept` translates to code like this:

```
public function testSystemUnderTestOnlyInvokesFoo() {
    $myMock = $this->createMock(ClassWithManyMethods::class);
    $myMock->expects($this->never)
       ->method($this->logicalNot($this->matches('foo')));
    $myMock->expects($this->once())->method('foo');

    function_under_test($myMock);
}
```

If you have several methods you want to exclude, use `matchesRegex` like this:

```
$myMock->expects($this->never)
   ->method($this->logicalNot($this->matchesRegex('/foo|bar|baz/')));
```